# Dynamic functions in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to explore the dynamic capabilities of F# for situations where I can't express some function with the static type system.  As such, I'm trying to create a `mapN` function for (say) `Option` types, but I'm having trouble creating a function with a dynamic number of arguments.  I've tried:

```
let mapN<'output> (f : obj) args =
  let rec mapN' (state:obj) (args' : (obj option) list) = 
    match args' with
    | Some x :: xs -> mapN' ((state :?> obj -> obj) x) xs
    | None _ :: _ -> None
    | [] -> state :?> 'output option

  mapN' f args

let toObjOption (x : #obj option) = 
  Option.map (fun x -> x :> obj) x

let a = Some 5
let b = Some "hi"
let c = Some true

let ans = mapN<string> (fun x y z -> sprintf "%i %s %A" x y z) [a |> toObjOption; b |> toObjOption; c |> toObjOption]
```

(which takes the function passed in and applies one argument at a time) which *compiles*, but then at runtime I get the following:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ans@47' to type 
'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.
```

I realize that it would be more idiomatic to either create a computation expression for options, or to define `map2` through `map5` or so, but I specifically want to explore the dynamic capabilities of F# to see whether something like this would be possible.

Is this just a concept that can't be done in F#, or is there an approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain why your approach does not work, the problem is that you cannot cast a function of type `int -> int` (represented as `FSharpFunc<int, int>`) to a value of type `obj -> obj` (represented as `FSharpFunc<obj, obj>`). The types are the same generic types, but the cast fails because the generic parameters are different.

If you insert a lot of boxing and unboxing, then your function actually works, but this is probably not something you want to write:

```
let ans = mapN<string> (fun (x:obj) -> box (fun (y:obj) -> box (fun (z:obj) -> 
  box (Some(sprintf "%i %s %A" (unbox x) (unbox y) (unbox z)))))) 
    [a |> toObjOption; b |> toObjOption; c |> toObjOption]
```

If you wanted to explore more options possible thanks to dynamic hacks - then you can probably do more using F# reflection. I would not typically use this in production (simple is better - I'd just define multiple map functions by hand or something like that), but the following runs:

```
let rec mapN<'R> f args = 
  match args with 
  | [] -> unbox<'R> f
  | x::xs ->
      let m = f.GetType().GetMethods() |> Seq.find (fun m -> 
        m.Name = "Invoke" && m.GetParameters().Length = 1)
      mapN<'R> (m.Invoke(f, [| x |])) xs

mapN<obj> (fun a b c -> sprintf "%d %s %A" a b c) [box 1; box "hi"; box true]
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation of why my solution doesn't work and how to get it to work.  I agree that the dynamic solution is pretty gross and not suitable for production.  Not that that changes my opinion of F# at all, I was just curious of the capabilities there.

Answer (score 5):

I think you would only be able to take that approach with reflection.

However, there are other ways to solve the overall problem without having to go dynamic or use the other static options you mentioned. You can get a lot of the same convenience using `Option.apply`, which you need to define yourself (or take from a library). This code is stolen and adapted from [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/#apply):

```
module Option =
    let apply fOpt xOpt = 
        match fOpt,xOpt with
        | Some f, Some x -> Some (f x)
        | _ -> None

let resultOption =  
    let (<*>) = Option.apply

    Some (fun x y z -> sprintf "%i %s %A" x y z)
    <*> Some 5
    <*> Some "hi"
    <*> Some true
```

Comment: For OP; this is a functional "pattern" called Applicative. Very useful and the way I would do it too in a language like F#. In statically typed languages that don't support partial application (C#, kotlin, java and so on) I would generate an overload for 1 argument, 2 arguments and so on using a code gen tool. In C++ there's support for variadic generic argument lists so there we can write a function mapN that works like OP envisions it.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox, I had read that article on F# For Fun and Profit about the `apply` function, but I had completely forgotten that.  Thank you for pointing out its use here